# Difference between the methods of Contour Integration.

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

What is the difference between the two methods of contour integration( Cauchy's integral formula and Residue theorem) and in what cases they will yield the same answer?

Comment: Cauchy's integral formula can be seen as a special case of the residue theorem. They will always yield the same answer (if they apply).

Comment: @AntonioVargas THANKYOU